# Math.ceil not rounding the value

Tags: java

```
double totalInches = d * 0.3937;
double feetPart = totalInches / 12;
int inchesPart = (int) Math.ceil(totalInches - (feetPart * 12));
return (feetPart) + "' " + inchesPart + "''";
```

I am getting a value `6.9999999 ' 0"`. I am returning a string, is it the reason why the decimals values in feet is not getting rounded off.

I tried without casting too. `double inchesPart = Math.ceil(totalInches - (feetPart * 12));`, but still i get the same result.

Comment: I'm confused. `feetPart` is **not** supposed to be rounded according to your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely you need:

`int feetPart = (int)Math.floor(totalInches / 12);`

or just:

`int feetPart = (int)(totalInches / 12);`

Comment: Wouldn't `double feetPart = (totalInches / 12.0);` also work?

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla I'm pretty sure that wouldn't round the answer

Comment: @paul: thanks paul, i am getting 5.0' 6.0" now... if i have to remove the .0 from that, what should i do.

Comment: are you sure that `feetPart` and `inchesPart` are both `int`s?

Comment: Casting to an integer does a floor anyway.  You can do `int feetPart = (int)(totalInches / 12);`

Answer (score 1):

To get the two parts you can use

```
int totalInches = (int) (d * 0.3937);
int feetPart = totalInches / 12;
int feetInchPart = totalInches % 12;
```